# Accessing lower level data in JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I've done some searching, but I've been unable to fully understand how this is done. I am relatively new to jQuery and JSON. Basically, I have a massive JSON document that I am connecting to and displaying various data from it. The data I need is the Supplier Label, which is nested three levels down, and I'm unsure how to return it.

The JSON

```
    {
    "@order": "1",
    "category": {
        "@id": "204",
        "label": "Category 1",
        "suppliers": {
            "supplier": {
                "label": "Business 1",
                "customicons": [
                    {
                        "@id": "images/img2.jpeg",
                        "#text": "random icon"
                    }
                ]
            }
         }
       }
    },
```

Here's the script that I've made to form an unordered list. I tried item.category.suppliers.supplier.label, which obviously isn't working. Do I need to add some function that iterates through each sub level? How do I get to that label?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.getJSON('jsonarray.json', 
    function(data) {

      var items = [];

      $.each(data, function(i,item) {

        items.push('<li id="' + item["@order"] + '"><label for="supplier"><input id="supplier" name="supplier" type="checkbox" class="checkbox"/>' + item.category.suppliers.supplier.label + '</label></li>');

      });

      $('<ul/>', {
        'class': 'checklist-supplier cl2',
        html: items.join('')
      }).appendTo('.list_filter_supplier_side');
    });

});
</script>
```

So, basically the question is how do I access sub level data in JSON using jQuery? Any clarification is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If `item["@order"]` works, `item.category.suppliers.supplier.label` with your example JSON should work fine. Try setting a breakpoint on the `items.push` line and inspecting each step of the chain.

Comment: Please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: Order works fine if I remove item.category.suppliers.supplier. For now, I am getting the error "item.category.suppliers.supplier is undefined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is the JSON in some sort of response?  If so you can do something like this:

```
var d = {
"@order": "1",
"category": {
    "@id": "204",
    "label": "Category 1",
    "suppliers": {
        "supplier": {
            "label": "Business 1",
            "customicons": [
                {
                    "@id": "images/img2.jpeg",
                    "#text": "random icon"
                }
            ]
        }
     }
   }
}

//just show the label    
alert(d.category.suppliers.supplier.label);
```

**[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/XvyQd/)**

Comment: Not too sure how to implement this in my current code. Do I need to assign a variable to $.getJSON('jsonarray.json', function(data)? How would I use that variable as I loop through the entire JSON file? Would it then become d.category.suppliers.supplier.label

Comment: What does your full data set look like?  You could loop through an array of those records.  How is your data stored?

Comment: Right now, I am working with a local example of the JSON. I have it stored as a json file in the same directory as the html file. The data set is similar to what I've posted, except that it contains about 100 records. I am doing it this way to mock it up quickly.

Comment: Is it in a JSON array, or will it be?  Also - what happens if you console.log(item);  Are you able to see all of the nested fields?

Comment: Actually, it will be in an array. So, should I be iterating through with the i?

Answer (score 1):

Except that, You are using the correct way of accessing the data

```
item.category.suppliers.supplier.label
```

Validate your JSON using [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com) to confirm its validation

Comment: I wasn't sure how to deal with the @ in the data, so that was the way that I decided to approach it. It works for now, until I can fix the actual problem. I previously checked to see if my json was valid in jsonlint and it came back valid. I am getting an error item.category.suppliers.supplier is undefined